# Changing Stack to have limited depth in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Apple have given an example of a traditional pop and pull stack in their programming guide:

```
struct Stack<Element> {
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
}
```

My intention was to create a structure from which to calculate a "moving average" of the contents while adding extra values during my code - averaging over the last 10 items I've added to the stack.

Can the above be modified to do this, or am I better using a new structure that looks something like the below:

```
struct Avg<Element> {
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func additem(_item: Element) {
       if items.count<10 {
           items.append(item)
       } else {
           for i in (1...10).reversed() {
               items[i] = items[i-1]
           }
           items[0]=item
       }
   }
// more functions
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`items.remove(at: 0)` or `items.removeFirst()` would be more efficient
than your loop to remove the first array element.

But what I would actually do is to use the internal array as a "ring buffer" and overwrite
elements once the window size has been reached, instead of moving
all elements. Something like this:

```
struct Avg<Element> {
    let windowSize: Int
    var totalCount: Int
    var items: [Element]

    init(windowSize: Int) {
        self.windowSize = windowSize
        self.totalCount = 0
        self.items = []
    }

    mutating func additem(_ newItem: Element) {
        if items.count < windowSize {
            items.append(newItem)
        } else {
            items[totalCount % windowSize] = newItem
        }
        totalCount += 1
    }

    // more functions
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd gotten hung up on adding the new item at `[0]` but it's just as easy to add it at `[11]` and then delete `[0]`

Comment: I've just realised your solution is so much more elegant than I originally thought. If it doesn't matter what order elements were added to the array (as in my oversimplified explanation) this "ring buffer" is an excellent idea, and a fantastic implementation of it. Kudos!

Comment: @MartinKS: Even if the order matters:  `totalCount % windowSize` is the index of the least recently added items, so you can always reconstruct in which order the elements were added.